# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to model.AdminPopulate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, casting, classcastexception

I tried to convert the List I got from Hibernate to AdminPopulate type using the following code, and I got this error

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to model.AdminPopulate

```
public class Test
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
     SubUser subUser=new SubUser();        

     List subUserList=subUser.getSubUserAll();

     List<AdminPopulate> subUserListAdminPop=new ArrayList<AdminPopulate>();

     for(Object p:subUserList)
     {
         subUserListAdminPop.add((AdminPopulate)p);
     }         

     for(AdminPopulate p:subUserListAdminPop)
     {
         System.out.println("first ="+p.getFirstName());
     }
 }
```

}

....and this is the getSubUserAll() method

```
 public List getSubUserAll()
{
    Session session=null;
    List resultsList=null;

    try
    {
       CreateHibernateSession hbSession=new CreateHibernateSession();

       session=hbSession.getHBSession();

       String sql = "SELECT SubUser.FirstName,\n" +
                    "SubUser.LastName,\n" +
                    "SubUser.UserName,\n" +
                    "SubUserType.Name\n" +
                    "FROM SubUser\n" +
                    "INNER JOIN SubUserType ON SubUser.idSubUserType = SubUserType.idSubUserType\n" +
                    "WHERE SubUserType.idSubUserType !=  0";

       Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);  

       resultsList = query.list(); 

       return resultsList;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        session.close();
    }
    return resultsList;
}
```

Comment: It means you're casting an instance of `Object` to `model.AdminPopulate` which isn't an acceptable cast.

Comment: @Sufian: I am sure he already knows that...

Comment: @JustCause wishful thinking. He wouldn't be asking like that if that was true.

Comment: @Sufian I am asking how to solve this. I already know that it isn't an acceptable cast. Looking for a way around it

Answer (score 1):

If `SubUser` class is mapped properly to the result of the query, then you can just call `query.addEntity(SubUser.class)` prior to executing the query.

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);  
query.addEntity(SubUser.class);
resultsList = query.list();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in Hibernate, but you are trying to cast an `array of objects`
 (Object[] -> [Ljava.lang.Object;), what means, that the method `Query.list` has returned multiple results in a row.  And if you look at your SQL, it is clear why, you are referencing two tables in the select.
I guess `Query.list` returned in every row an Object[2] with a SubUser in the first and a SubUserType in the second element.